# How to keep idle session from exiting

Tags: bash

I'm working remotely on a new CentOS 7 VM.  I have screen running with several open sessions.  I'm finding that if I leave one of the sessions idle for awhile, then try to come back to it, it's gone.  Nothing special going on in the sessions - ssh connections to other systems, mysqlclient, top, etc. - those all stay up.  But if I just leave a session sitting at the bash shell prompt, it disappears - I just watched one and it took about 10-11 minutes.

I've never had that happen before.  Any idea what's going on?

New information.  It's probably not screen.  I opened a new ssh session to this system and left it idle.  And it closed on me as well.  But this time I got a message:

```
timed out waiting for input: auto-logout
```

Off to google... probably some goofy shell setting?

Comment: When you say it "disappeared", was it that the `screen` session ended, or was it that a GUI window containing the `screen` session closed on you leaving the session still running but no longer connected and visible?

Comment: "disappeared" as in if I flip through the screen sessions (ctrl-a n, ctrl-a p) the session is no longer there.  Screen is still running.  There were 4 sessions, as counted with ctrl-a ".  Come back 10 minutes later and the 3 sessions with something going on are still there, and the idle bash session is just gone.

Comment: Is the `bash` variable `TMOUT` set to a positive integer? That's the number of seconds before an idle shell will close.

Comment: That's it exactly - our friendly neighborhood sysadmins saw fit to set it in /etc/profile.d/os-security.sh  It's all better now - thanks :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A `bash` shell can be configured to exit after a certain amount of idle time. This value is defined with the `TMOUT` variable.

For example, `TMOUT=300` will cause the shell to exit after 5 minutes (300 seconds) of inactivity.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was configured in `/etc/profile.d/tmout.sh` file and it was set as readonly and I could not modify it later on. I added the below line in my /etc/bash.bashrc file so it worked every time bash is initialized.

```
sed -i 's/TMOUT=900/TMOUT=0/g' /etc/profile.d/tmout.sh
```

Comment: That edits the file each time the script is executed. Is that _really_ what you intended?

Comment: My scenario is mostly a test environment and it is acceptable. Good that you highlighted so that any cautious user will be aware of it.